# jQuery Datatables Dropdown in Table can't Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using Datatables based on jQuery. 
I have a Datatable which has dropdown inputs within the table to modify the data in the table. 
Unfortunately I can't filter for the selected value in the dropdown. 
Any ideas on how to achieve that?

---

[image]

Comment: Do you mean "dropdown" or select? One of them is native HTML functionality and the other is not. Either way you need to show your HTML and JavaScript code for us to help.

Comment: I mean select. Its a standard HTML Table with a <select><option>Lorem ipsum</option></select> in it.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to filter the rows based on the value in your `Search:` input correct?

Comment: Yes that would be great. If the value in Search equals the selected value it should be shown.

Comment: Can we get a minimal code example that shows the problem?  Maybe mock it up in JSFiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0w4d0vmo/

Comment: Here's an example. DataTables unfortunately not working. Within the Search Field of the DataTables I want to Search for the Values in "Bearbeiter" Column